# Figure with minipage alignment issues

Tags: floats, minipage

I have a figure block with 2 'minipage', each having a figure. When I typeset the document, the figure goes to the top of the page instead of being in the sub-section where I am defining it. The following is the code I am using to do this.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.4\linewidth]{sample.png}
    \caption{Collection Definition}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.4\linewidth]{tree.png}
    \caption{Collection Result}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: add `\usepackage{flafter}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the optional position specifier `[htbp]` for the `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Some section}
\begin{figure}[htb]                    %% here
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Collection Definition}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Collection Result}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

A must read: [Frank's answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/11232).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. What does [htb] stand for?

Comment: @eddyrokr: `h` means `possibly here`, `t` means `possible at the top` and `b` is `possibly at the bottom`. if you put a `!` in front (`[!htb]`), it becomes more compelling than a request (I want it here/top/bottom - a demand not a request ;-)). There is also `p` specifier meaning to put figure in a separate float only page.

Comment: @eddyrokr Read this excellent answer for details: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/11232

Comment: That was helpful :)